# Proof of Stake Resources for research

Tags: proof-of-stake, consensus

I need resources/links/articles for proof of stake consensus algorithm for research analysis. If anyone has any resources, please do share.

Answer (score 1):

The first resource I would point you to is the official Ethereum Foundation's explanation of it:

https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/consensus-mechanisms/pos/

Next, I quite like Vitalik Buterin's blogpost as well:

https://vitalik.ca/general/2020/11/06/pos2020.html

Finally, if you are looking for something more formal, I found this IEEE paper on it quite resourceful as well:

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8746079

Comment: Nice! Another one I'd add is https://eth.wiki/en/concepts/proof-of-stake-faqs